# Secure the 2-stages approval application using SharePoint &amp; Power Apps &amp; Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint, office365, powerapps, power-automate, power-platform

We have a travel request application. where a user submit a request which should go into 2 stages of approval process before it gets Final Approval.

Now we did the following:-

1. Create a SharePoint list which contain those fields; Title, Description, StareDate, EndDate, FirstApproval (the requestor direct manager), SecondApproval (the requester regional approval), Statues (system-generated with those options; open, first-approved, second-approved, Final-Approved).
2. Power Apps, which send emails to the first-approval and the second-approval users , and show-hide the Approved & Reject buttons based on the item status.
3. Power Automate,to set item-level permissions, so for example when the item needs first-approval only the approval's direct manager can edit the item, while all stakeholders can read-only.

now the process is not 100% secure, as a requestor using API call or using SharePoint built-in forms, can easily create a new request and define its status as Final-Approved. so in other words the requestor can bypass the Power Apps business logic. so how we can secure our process? so if an item has a status = "Final-Approved", then we can 100% sure that it actually went through the 2 approvals users?

One Approach i am thinking of, is as follow:-

1. To create additional SharePoint list >> which stores the ItemID + ItemStatus.
2. Grant all users Read-Only on this new list while grant the service account Contribute.
3. Update this new list from Power automate Only. so for example only if the submitter's direct manager did the approval, to change the status inside the new list to First-Approved, and so on.. Also only if the submitter's regional manager approve the request + there is already an approval from the direct manager to change the status from First-Approved to Second-Approval.. so what ever the status is inside the new lit i can be sure that it has not been hacked, as end-user will have read-only on this new list.. can anyone advice please?

Thanks

Comment: Hello John, seems you are new, as a suggestion, for other to help you on SO.

`You need start/reword it with a clear question`, what failed/based on what you tried &  please `list a code sample` . In short this could be done, but its not clear what specifically is your question and are you trying to do it via designer or code/programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this question is not unique to you, many SharePoint developers need to make specific configurations or use some artifices to ensure a certain process developed in SharePoint.

Using exclusive/custom permission control into List and uses the PowerAutomate layer to conntrol List Item permission only to approver will secures some update from Rest API, for example.

If you want to block New Insert items and/or block Update items by PowerApps, you can substitute the instruction into "OnEdit" and/or "OnNew" events using `ResetForm(SharePointForm1);; RequestHide();;` with this instructions in these events block some user to create or update SharePoint Items.

Into SharePoint list settings, in advanced settings, you can disable attachments, disable comments in list item, disable search, disable quick edit, disable launch form in dialog.

I think that's all.

Comment: but even if i disable attachments, disable comments in list item, disable search, disable quick edit, disable launch form in dialog, do some customization inside power apps >> user can call the list rest api and do whatever update/create they want.. am i correct?

Comment: Good question! Yes, user may call list by API, BUT remember: to consume list by API, it's requires a Bearer token, and this Bearer Token provided from authentication; although users can authenticate, has a second layer for authorization, and the authorization can be controlled from site level or list level permissions.

Comment: yes and the user will have contribute of the list otherwise they will not be able to add items through power apps.. i think you did not get my main question

Comment: Owh man, to consume REST API by end-user, requires an advanced knowledge about SharePoint Rest API approach to contribute into the list. BUT, if your requirement is want to block Rest API consuming, remove permissions for all users into the candidate list and use [SharePoint Add-In App Permission approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/add-in-permissions-in-sharepoint), it is the only way to meet this requirement.

Comment: ok thanks for the info, but how i can use the SP Add-in approach to secure the approval ? second question, did you have the chance to look into the appraoch  i am thinking of, which include creating additional list ?

Comment: Using the SharePoint Add-In Hosted App like the principal forms: or to register new items or to approvement flow; for example: the add-in form to include new items will need to be securely into a page where the system admins have permission and the another form (for approvemment) you may reuse the PowerAutomate flow to give exclusive permission to access this page-form. About your approach suggestion, it sounds good, BUT the inherent risk of messing up the main list via API will continue.